# How to type safely pass props conditionally to a functional component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, overloading

I have this scenario:

```
const enum Tag {
  Friday: 'Friday',
  Planing: 'Planing'
}
type Props = {
  tag: Tag,
  // tour: (location: string) => void,
  // time: (date: Date) => void,
}
const Child: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  // some logic
}
```

if `tag`'s type is `Tag.Friday`, I need to pass `tour`, if `tag`'s type is `Tag.Planning`, I need to pass `time`.
I have considered optional property, but it seems not suitable to this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions).

```js
const enum Tag {
    Friday = 'Friday',
    Planing = 'Planing',
}

type Option1 = {
    tag: Tag.Friday,
    tour: (location: string) => void,
}

type Option2 = {
    tag: Tag.Planing,
    time: (date: Date) => void,
}

const Test1: FC<Option1 | Option2> = (props) => {
    if (props.tag === Tag.Friday) {
        return <div onClick={() => props.tour('hello')}>This</div>;
    } else {
        return <div onClick={() => props.time(new Date())}>That</div>;
    }
};

const Test2 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            OK:
            <Test1 tag={Tag.Friday} tour={() => {}} />
            <Test1 tag={Tag.Planing} time={() => {}} />

            Error:
            <Test1 tag={Tag.Planing} tour={() => {}} />
        </>
    );
};
```